Import intellisense for custom package is not working in vs code
Hi i am creating 2 simple test projects where project A is a custom NPM package and project B consume it. The issue is that there is no import intellisense.
My folder structure looks like this:

project-a/src/index.ts
export function MRTAdd(v1: number, v2: number): number {
    return v1 + v2;
}

project-a/package.json
{
  "name": "npm-project-a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}

project-a/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

Next i ran npm build which gives me the tsc build inside dist folder
Next step i did is to npm link inside root of project-a, and then in project-b i npm link npm-project-a
Now that i see it is install inside node_modules, then when i tried typing MRTAdd i see this

Although typing the import manually works

Please advise!

Did you add npm-project-a as a dependency in the package.json of npm-project-b?

Nope, but if i do add it then intellisense still not work, this shouldnt be the case as i other libs like redux can be detected in the sub node_module

@TimHansen i tried your suggestion again, now it is working. npm link first then add the package name in package.json, but in addition i will need to use tsup to build the npm package

Awesome! npm-link always felt somewhat finicky to me...

From Tim Hansen answer in addition i found that using tsup with added package name to package.json works.
To package up your NPM in project A

npm i -D tsup
use the minimum tsconfig.json provided below
use the minimum tsup.config.ts
in your package.json script "build": "tsup"
npm link in your project

To use project A in project B

npm link project A
Add project A package name to package.json

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Node10",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

tsup.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'tsup';
 
export default defineConfig({
    format: ['cjs', 'esm'],
    entry: ['./src/index.ts'],
    dts: true,
    shims: true,
    skipNodeModulesBundle: true,
    clean: true,
});

package.json
{
  "name": "npm-package-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsup": "^8.3.5",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }
}

